# play framework not receiving big post data

Tags: java, http, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been trying to send big post data to play 2.0 controller to no avail. I use `MultipartFormData` body parser but any form field larger than `100KB` returns empty.

Here is the code:

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.MultipartFormData.class)

RequestBody body = request().body();

if(body.asMultipartFormData() != null) {

Logger.debug("size: " + body.asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded().size());

String data = body.asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded().get("xmlData")[0];

//data returns empty.
```

I also tried different body parsers but none of them works. How can I read big post values (up to 1mb) in `play 2.0`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `application.conf` - `parsers.formUrlEncoded.maxLength=1024K`.

Or you can try adding maxLength parameter to your BodyParser like this:

`@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.MultipartFormData.class, maxLength = 1024 * 1024)` (didn't test this though).

You can read this in detail [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaBodyParsers) in the section called "Max content length"